# How to get array value as return value on curl php request?

Tags: php, curl

I am having hard time using curl PHP as I am new to PHP. The problem is that I am not getting any return value from a curl request. There is a remote file I am accessing which has this code:

### test.php:

```
$test->getCall();
public function getCall() {
  $var = array('fname'=>'jack','lname'=>'williams');
  return $var;
}
```

The script from which I am making the call.

### requestVal.php

```
try{
  $ch = curl_init();
  if (FALSE === $ch){
    throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.xyz.com/app/src/test.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $p_result = curl_exec($ch);
  var_dump($p_result);
  print_r($p_result);
  if (FALSE === $p_result) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error(), curl_errno());
    curl_close($ch);
  } else{
    curl_close($ch);
    return $p_result;
  }
}catch(Exception $e) {
  trigger_error(sprintf('Curl failed with error #%d: %s',$e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

I don't get any value in `$p_result` nor an exception `curl_error()`.

Comment: Is getCall a method of a class?

Comment: in actual code yes, and i call it by its object which $test in this case

Comment: Your problem is not curl in PHP. Instead fix the script first that should return something and test it without the scond PHP script. Curl will only take (as text) what the script your request with curl does return. So test the return value of the script first and then you will find your actual error. Asking for PHP curl here is not constructive so, it's just the wrong end. So do some basic debugging first and you should be able to see more clear. E.g. request `test.php` with the [curl commandline client](http://curl.haxx.se/) and see the output. Always a useful tool to have at hand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No matter what you echo in your `test.php`, curl will read it as a `String`. In your case, you echo nothing. You call a function that returns the array, but you don't print the array, so nothing is sent to output. If you want to get the same array in `requestVal.php` after curl request, you need to encode it in some way, I would suggest JSON as it's easy to start with. For a quick example, in place of `$test->getCall();` you could do:

```
echo json_encode($test->getCall());
```

And in `requestVal.php`:

```
$array = json_decode(trim($p_result), TRUE);
print_r($array);
```

You can find each function description at `php.net`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using curl you should expect exactly the same result as you'll get if you run your test.php script in any browser. So, if your test.php is like:

```
echo "123";
```

in your browser you'll see "123" and that's also you'll get inside your `$p_result` variable. If your test.php is like:

```
function foo() {
    return "123";
}

foo();
```

You see nothing in browser and get nothing in your `$p_result` as well.

So, try change your test.php in something like that:

```
public function getCall() {
    $var = array('fname'=>'jack','lname'=>'williams');
    return $var;
}

var_dump($test->getCall()); // of course you will show these values in better way (depends on your needs)
```

Answer (score 0):

like Ranty said, you can return a string at **test.php** code

```
$test->getCall();
public function getCall() {
  $var = array('fname'=>'jack','lname'=>'williams');
  echo serialize($var);
}
```

So, you can caught a serialization data at **requestVal.php** code, by unserialize data from remote server

```
unserialize($content)
```