# Trouble printing multi-dimensional array sent with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [10209064245580796] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [hashed_token] => ) [1] => Array ( [password] => ) [2] => Array ( [email] => klemen.pevc@gmail.com ) ) [10207252567926988] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [hashed_token] => ) [1] => Array ( [password] => 716b64c0f6bad9ac405aab3f00958dd1 ) [2] => Array ( [email] => milvuk@gmail.com ) ) )
```

That I made this way:
`$users` looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 10209064245580796 [1] => 10207252567926988)
```

`$arrayOfFields` looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => hashed_token [1] => password [2] => email )
```

So:

```
$array=array();
foreach($users as $user){
   $array[$user]=array();
   foreach($arrayOfFields as $getFieldValue) {
      $user = '' . $user . '';
      $query = "SELECT `$getFieldValue` FROM $table WHERE `$column`= $user";
      $result = $mysqli->query($query);
      $fetchResult = $result->fetch_assoc();
      $getFieldValue = '' . $getFieldValue . '';
      $finalValue = $fetchResult[$getFieldValue];
      array_push($array[$user] ,array($getFieldValue=>$finalValue));
   }
}
```

And after this two `foreachs` I get an array `$array` as shown above in first example that I'm sending via `cURL` with this code:

```
$data = array('facebook_app_id' => $facebook_app_id, 'facebook_ids' => $facebook_ids,'values_for_custom_fields' => $array);

   $endpoint_url = 'https://servis-racunara.net/api/index.php';
   $curl = curl_init($endpoint_url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Authorization: Token ".$token));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);

   //you do not need to print results, this is just for debugging purposes
   $result = $curl_response;
   print_r($result);
```

So inside script of this endpoint https://servis-racunara.net/api/index.php (on which I'm sending some data, including `$array`) when i do `print_r($_POST)` I get an array like this:

```
Array ( [facebook_app_id] => 1512823699024883 [facebook_ids] => 10209064245580796,10207252567926988[values_for_custom_fields] => Array )
```

So, under key `values_for_custom_fields` is stored `$array` array that I need to process. When I do `print_r($_POST['values_for_custom_fields']);` it just says 'Array', and when I try this:

```
foreach($_POST['values_for_custom_fields'] as $anything) {
       echo($anything);//same with print_r
}
```

Server says :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665532/how-to-get-array-value-as-return-value-on-curl-php-request) look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772096/posting-multidimensional-array-with-php-and-curl) thread too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've chosen wrong format for sending data. In your code you use ***form submission format***, namely `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (as it is used by default in CURL). Neither of [form submission formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) support nested data (arrays). In other words you **cannot** send nested arrays in POST request as form-encoded data.

So you have to use other format to send your data. I would suggest to use [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - popular format which allow any level of nesting. In this case you have to JSON-encode data before sending and decode - when receiving them in the endpoint script. Also you have to set appropriate `Content-type` header for request: `application/json`.

```
...
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Token ".$token,
    "Content-type: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
...
```